# Additionnal promise parameter javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

So i got this

```
for(var i =0;i<result.length;i++){
    User.find(result[i].user).then((err,user)=>{
        resultArray.push({name : result[i].name, userName : user.name});     
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work because the loops end before the promises resolves.
So i wanted to know if i could give a copy of i to the User.find() callback?
I don't know any way to keep the data synced between the result and user array, since i don't know in which order the promises are gonna be resolved.

Comment: `result.forEach(res=> User.find(res.user).then(...`

Comment: Okay but, how can i know that every request has been completed?

Comment: @KillianAllegrain for these sorts of things you may want to consider using something like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) or Promise.all

Comment: @KillianAllegrain it doesn't tell you when the promise returns, but with the `forEach` method, you're getting a copy of the array elements, and aren't relying on a constantly changing index (`i`) to access the result array

Comment: Just leave it open ;) Maybe someone else will stumble upon your question

Answer (score 0):

Mentioned in the comments section, you want to resolve all users. You can use the Array method `map` to generate an Array of Promises to then pass to Promise.all, like so:

```
Promise.all(
  result.map( res => User.find( ... ) )
)
  .then( result => {
    // all resolved users are in result
  } );
```

Comment: So perfect ! Love you

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to accept my answer :)